# A perfect set results by removing the intervals in such a way as to create no isolated points.

Tags: real-analysis

Here is a statement in Zygmund's Measure and Integral that confuses me on Page 8:

> Any closed set in $\mathbb{R}^1$ can be constructed by deleting a countable number of open disjoint intervals from $\mathbb{R}^1$. A perfect set results by removing the intervals in such a way as to create no isolated points; thus, we would not remove any two open intervals with a common endpoint.
>
> **Definition** A perfect set $C$ is a closed set each of whose points is a limit point of $C$.

I don't understand - why removing the intervals results a prefect set?

Comment: Your title and question seem to have nothing to do with each other. Could you also give the statement you've quoted more context and explain exactly what part you don't understand?

Comment: If two open intervals with a common endpoint are removed then that common point will be an isolated point.

Comment: Do you know what a perfect set is? It's very hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Yes @dfeuer. A perfect set is defined to be a set contains only its limit point. And I am confused why removing the intervals results a prefect set?

Comment: Added and corrected. Thanks @DanielRust.

Comment: It contains only its limit points, meaning that every element of it is a limit point, and thus is *not* an ____.

Comment: THanks @njguliyev, so now my only concern is why it results a perfect set..?

Comment: oh, interval/non-limit point... @dfeuer?

Comment: Huh? What do you call a point in a set that's not a limit point of that set?

Comment: @dfeuer interior point...

Comment: Jellyfish, I think the best approach at this juncture would be for you to review the definitions.

Comment: I am confused, what do you mean? Is my answer to your question what is a point not limit incorrect? @dfeuer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to show how, by starting with $\mathbb{R}$ and removing only non-overlapping open intervals, no two of which share an end point, the resulting set is a perfect set.

First of all, an easier definition of a perfect set to use (in this case) is a subset $A$ of a metric space $X$ which has no isolated points. An isolated point of $A$ is a point $x\in A\subset X$ such that there exists an open set $U\subset X$ such that $U\cap A=\{x\}$. You may like to try and prove that this is an equivalent definition yourself.

Now, suppose that the set $A$ constructed as described above had an isolated point $x$ (and so was not a perfect subset of $\mathbb{R}$). Let $U$ be such that $U\cap A=\{x\}$ and let $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ be an open interval centered at $x$ with radius $\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is small enough so that $B_{\epsilon}(x)\subset U$.

Now, as $B_{\epsilon}(x)\setminus\{x\}$ has empty intersection with $A$ and is an open set (equal to the union of two disjoint open intervals $(x-\epsilon,x)\cup (x,x+\epsilon)$), and we have not removed any overlapping open intervals from $\mathbb{R}$, at some point an open interval $(x-\alpha,x)$ was removed with $\alpha\geq\epsilon$ and also $(x,x+\beta)$ with $\beta\geq\epsilon$. However, this contradicts the condition that we removed open interval no two of which shared an end point. We conclude that no such isolated point can exist.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just give a few of the definitions of related terms. Let $S$ be a subset of a topological space $X$.

Let $x\in X$.

Then:

1. $x$ is in the *closure* of $S$ iff every open set containing $x$ contains an element of $S$.
2. $x$ is a *limit point* of $S$ iff every open set containing $x$ contains an element of $S\setminus \{x\}$. That is, iff $x$ is in the closure of $S\setminus \{x\}$
3. $x$ is an *interior point* of $S$ iff there is an open set $U$ such that $x\in U\subseteq S$. That is, iff $x$ is *not* in the closure of $X\setminus S$.
4. $x$ is an *isolated point* of $S$ iff for some open set $U$, $U\cap S = \{x\}$.