# Is $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k},1\right)$ a countable union? Is it closed?

Tags: real-analysis

Is this guy a countable union? Closed?

> $$\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k},1\right)$$

The problem is: if so, I found trouble with the claim:

> Any closed set in $\mathbb{R}^1$ can be constructed by deleting a countable number of open disjoint intervals from $\mathbb{R}^1$.

From [A perfect set results by removing the intervals in such a way as to create no isolated points.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474626/a-perfect-set-results-by-removing-the-intervals-in-such-a-way-as-to-create-no-is)

In which, there is 
Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't contain 1, which is a limit point.

Comment: Got it, thanks @FrancisAdams

Comment: Anything of the form $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\cdots\cdots$ is a countable union.  But these open intervals are certainly not disjoint, and it's not clear what it has to do with the "claim" you quote.  If this were a closed set, the intervals to be deleted would have to be outside this set, not within it.

Comment: Dear @MichaelHardy - yes I realized it, thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\displaystyle\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} (\frac{1}{k},1) = (0,1)$

Note the index set is a countable set.